# React Native TypeScript Images & Static Assets

Tags: typescript, react-native

I was following along in the [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Native-Starter) that Microsoft put out on how to convert your ReactNative project to TypeScript.

Everything worked great until I reached the point where I needed to include images in my project. Obviously `tsc` doesn't pack up images into the outdir, so my question is **how are people currently using images or other static assets when using ReactNative with TypeScript?**

Comment: It works the same as straight JS. Use ```require```

Answer (score 11):

I'am not sure if this is the best approach,the way I solved it is,

Create a file in the root folder containing images(Should be read by typescript) or any other folder as per your folder structure.
Name it "your-name-here.d.ts" (d.ts should be the extension.Its used by typescript engine)

```
 declare module '*.jpg' {
  import { ImageSourcePropType } from 'react-native';
  const value: ImageSourcePropType;
  export default value;
}
```

ImageSourcePropType is the type expected by the source argument in Image

Now where ever an image is used can be used as

```
import SampleIcon from '../images/sample-image.jpg';

<Image src={SampleIcon} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
```

Answer (score 6):

## Option 1 - Move images folder to root of project:

The way I ended up solving the problem was to move the images up to the root dir of the project, rather than living within the `src` directory.

#### Create an `images` folder in the project root

```
images/
  - sample-image.jpg
src/
  - App.tsx
output/
  - App.js
```

#### Reference the image using relative path

```
const image = require('../images/sample-image.jpg');
...
<Image src={image} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
```

Since the shape of the output should match the shape of the source directory, referencing a top-level image directory works just fine.

## Option 2 - Use `copyfiles` npm package:

This option allows you to keep images inline, but requires an extra step when rebuilding your project.

#### Install `copyfiles`

`npm i -D copyfiles`

#### Add the following to `package.json` scripts

```
...
"start": "npm run build && node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
"build": "npx tsc && npm run add-assets",
"add-assets": "copyfiles -u 1 'src/**/!(*.js|*.jsx|*.map|*.ts|*.tsx)' lib/",
...
```

Now execute `npm run build` or `npm start` and our nice new package `copyfiles` will copy over any non-source file to the out directory.

**NOTE**: You may need to update the glob as needed to ignore files that you do not want copied over to the outdir.

Comment: The first option helped. Bu think it will be not the best option for production application.

Comment: I was thinking about using symlinks, is there anything wrong with that approach?

Comment: Hey Justin
Your #1 suggestion worked great for me in the past. But now, when I try to run my project on a new computer, all static images are not showing up - seeing just nothing instead (the project does run)
Any idea what might cause this?