# How can I make typescript compile only needed files?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); answering any part would do.

**X:** I want to generate multiple bundles out of a single source tree. I'm aware of [webpack supporting this](http://codys.club/blog/2015/07/04/webpack-create-multiple-bundles-with-entry-points/), but I'm afraid, I can't use it. For example, my Router gets fed by one or more maps mapping a route (string) to a page (component). I'm storing these maps in separate files and comment importing and using them out as needed (I wrote a simple script doing this for me).

*Is there a better solution?*

**Y:** So when building the *admin* bundle, the *user* pages are not reachable from the `index.tsx`. Nonetheless, I'm getting typescript errors for them. The same happens even when I create a new unused file containing an error.

*How can I avoid compiling unused files?*

---

I'm not posting here all my config files as I hope, there's a simple setting for this somewhere. I'll do it when needed. Alone the list makes me depressed:

```
.babelrc
.env
.eslintrc
.gitignore
config-overrides.js
package.json
tsconfig.json
tslint-imports.json
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain this isn't possible with just TypeScript, unless you were to create a new (temporary) directory and hard link the relevant files to the new directory. Apart from that, I'd think you'd need some sort of build tool like rollup or webpack, as you mentioned.

Comment: hmm tried restricting the input files with `exclude` and `include` in tsconfig.json? If user pages aren't `import`ed anywhere in your code (no module resolution) and files are excluded from compilation via above config settings, you shouldn't get compile errors. It requires a bit manual effort, as you say you comment file imports out for the build (if I understood correctly)

Comment: @ford04 Yes, this should work.... and the manual effort of commenting lines out/in has been automated easily. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a partial answer, but hopefully it will take you in the right direction. Typescript looks at tsconfig.json. Assuming your initiation is from an npm script, you can specify which tsconfig to use with the `--project` flag, like `tsc --project tsconfig-1.json`.

In your tsconfig.json file, only include the entry file, like

```
include: [
    "src/app/index.ts"
]
```

If you have something like `"src/**/*"`, then it will process all files. But it you specify only the entry file, then it will process only the files in that *import tree*. The tree is defined by the `import`/`import()` statements.

For reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

If you want to create multiple bundles, then you'll need to run multiple npm scripts and have multiple tsconfig files or else specify the files from the command line.

Comment: I don't have any `include` in my `tsconfig.json`. I'll give it a try (and it'll most probably work). I've wrote a script commenting out/in some lines as needed, including imports, so the *import tree* should do the job.

Comment: Yeah that's probably it. To quote the tsconfig docs: 
> "If the "files" and "include" are both left unspecified, the compiler defaults to including all TypeScript (.ts, .d.ts and .tsx) files in the containing directory and subdirectories" ...

Comment: It nearly works, but with the import tree, I can't get images working. I'm using things like `import logo from './assets/logo.png'`, which now show `Cannot find module './assets/logo.png'.ts(2307)`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49248216/581205) may be related, though I'm using react-dom.

Comment: That sounds like something a webpack configuration would solve. Are you using something like `raw-loader`?

Comment: @maaartinus Is that image import issue related to your first  question at all? Did that also happen before?

Comment: @ford04 Sure, it is. By using `include`, it only compiles the reachable tree, which is perfect, but it somehow misses the images. It's problem I've never seen before and it fails the compilation. Note that it's TS who complains,not webpack.

Comment: @maaartinus did you declare an ambient wildcard module for your images, so that TypeScript doesn't complain if there are imports with unknown extensions? 
Create something like `ambient.d.ts` somewhere in your .ts src files, write in it: 
`declare module '*.png';` Look here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations

Comment: @ford04 I did not (I tried and failed). This could be the solution, however, before I started with this, it worked without them. And the syntax in your link is strange: According to it, your example should be something like `declare module '*.png!wtf';` and then I'd write `import 'logo.png!wtf'` instead of just `import 'logo.png'`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: No, that's just an example, syntax is dependent on the module loader/bundler. I think Webpack can have these suffixes. E.g. in my project, I include `declare module '*.scss';` to ignore SCSS file imports with TS.

Comment: @ford04 It took me a while, but now, I've got it working, just like you described. Many thanks!